# How can I determine the class of an object in Scala?

Tags: scala, subclass, instanceof, subtyping

I need to check that **y** is strictly an instance of **bar** AND NOT **foo**. How can I do this in Scala?

```
trait foo {}

trait bar extends foo {}

val x = new foo {}
val y = new bar {}

x.isInstanceOf[foo] // true
x.isInstanceOf[bar] // false

y.isInstanceOf[bar] // true
y.isInstanceOf[foo] // true (but I want it to return false)
```

Comment: If you need to do this, doesn't that imply that `bar` should not extend `foo`? What overall effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DNA In my case foo, bar, x and y have already been defined, so I was hoping I could identify the type difference within this hierarchy of traits, but it seems this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of your question says class, but the actual question uses traits. You can do something like this via runtime reflection with *classes*. Let's create a convenience method to obtain the `reflect.runtime.universe.Type` of an object:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def tpeOf[A](a: A)(implicit tt: TypeTag[A]): Type = tt.tpe
```

And some sample classes:

```
class Foo
class Bar extends Foo
val x = new Foo
val y = new Bar
```

We can use our `tpeOf` method to obtain the `Type` of `x` and `y`, and compare it with the `Type` of the `TypeTag` obtained using `typeOf`. This will yield the results you want.

```
scala> tpeOf(x) =:= typeOf[Foo]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> tpeOf(x) =:= typeOf[Bar]
res1: Boolean = false

scala> tpeOf(y) =:= typeOf[Foo]
res2: Boolean = false

scala> tpeOf(y) =:= typeOf[Bar]
res3: Boolean = true
```

But this does not work for traits, because in your example `y` is *not* an instance of `bar`, it's an instance of an anonymous class that *extends* `bar`. So using this method would always yield `false`.

```
trait foo {}
trait bar extends foo {}
val x = new foo {}
val y = new bar {}

scala> tpeOf(x) =:= typeOf[bar]
res4: Boolean = false   // As expected, `x` is not exactly `bar`
```

Comment: There is `<:<` that should be used here instead of `=:=`.

Comment: But the OP wants `tpeOf(y) =:= typeOf[Foo]` to be `false`, which it is. `<:<` would make it true.

Answer (score 3):

`getClass` would work if you would just create new instances. But you are creating new anonymous classes and instances of those.

For those the relationship to foo and to bar is exact the same: they are superclasses.